# sed command to swap characters

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, regular-expression, perl

My input file layout is: `mm/dd/yyyy,hh:mm,other fields`
I need to format it as:  `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:00,other fields`

sample input:

```
01/02/1998,09:30,0.4571,0.4613,0.4529,0.4592,6042175
01/02/1998,09:45,0.4592,0.4613,0.4529,0.4571,9956023
01/02/1998,10:00,0.4571,0.4613,0.455,0.4613,8939555
01/02/1998,10:15,0.4613,0.4697,0.4571,0.4697,12823627
01/02/1998,10:30,0.4676,0.4969,0.4613,0.4906,28145145
```

sample output:

```
1998-01-02 09:30:00,0.4571,0.4613,0.4529,0.4592,6042175
etc...
```

I tried to use:

```
sed -r 's/\(^[0-9][0-9])\(\/[0-9][0-9]\/)\(\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],)/\3\1\2/g
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/\(..\)\/\(..\)\/\(....\),\(.....\),\(.*\)/\3-\1-\2 \4:00,\5/'
```

Edited to include the input from the comments below:

```
sed -e 's#\(..\).\(..\).\(....\),\(.....\),#\3-\1-\2 \4:00,#'
```

Comment: It's not necessary to capture `\(.*\)` just to add it to the end (`\5`) of the replacement string

Comment: @MikeS - he doesn't need to match slashes - they're matched. He could just use another `.`

Comment: This to me looks the simplest, though I like chaos' solution in another answer as well. One minor change I would make: When you need a lot of backslashes in the search pattern, the first character after the 's' can define something else as a separator. E.g.: `sed -e 's#\(..\)/\(..\)/\(....\),\(.....\),\(.*\)#\3-\2-\1 \4:00,\5#'`  (thanks @mikeserv: my text was confusing. Fixed)

Comment: On second thought, my bad, jhilmer, if you're of the feminine persuasion. Whatever persuades you, it's a good `sed` script - but glenn's right about your trailing capture - it's not doing you any favors. I would drop it.

Answer (score 3):

That worked for me:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4}),([0-9:]{5})/\3-\1-\2 \4:00/g'
```

Match 2 digits (`([0-9]{2})`), slash, 2 digits (`([0-9]{2})`), slash, 4 digits (`([0-9]{4})`), and then digits and `:` (`([0-9:]{5})`). Replace it with the order you wish: `\3-\1-\2 \4:00` (year-month-day hour:minute:00).

Comment: I think I prefer the digit-and-count approach to the RE, if only because it's a LOT more intelligible.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 'y|/|-|
     s/,*\(.....\)-*\([^,]*\)/\2-\1/
     s// \1:00/2
'    <infile
```

OUTPUT:

```
1998-01-02 09:30:00,0.4571,0.4613,0.4529,0.4592,6042175
1998-01-02 09:45:00,0.4592,0.4613,0.4529,0.4571,9956023
1998-01-02 10:00:00,0.4571,0.4613,0.455,0.4613,8939555
1998-01-02 10:15:00,0.4613,0.4697,0.4571,0.4697,12823627
1998-01-02 10:30:00,0.4676,0.4969,0.4613,0.4906,28145145
```

With `sed` you don't usually need to try so hard - it often doesn't pay to try to explicitly enumerate the matches you're looking for. Rather, it is far simpler usually just to specify a few landmarks - delimiters - and let a pattern gobble up the interim for you.

Above `sed` first `y///` translates `/` characters to `-` characters. Next it references the first not-comma *(provided there are at least 5)* character in pattern-space and and the next four characters as `\1` while possibly ignoring a trailing `-`. It follows that on by referencing as many sequential `^`not-comma chars in `\2` as it might before the next occurring comma in pattern space. The result - for the first substitution - is that it puts `mm-dd` in `\1` before matching `-` and then `yyyy` in `\2`. So we swap those, drop the `-` and insert a new one on the other side like:

```
s/.../\2-\1/
```

And last we do it again - reusing the same pattern for a different purpose. When I do:

```
s// \1:00/2
```

I'm instructing `sed` to reuse the last regexp *(as signified by the `//` empty address)*, but this time to find the second occurrence of that pattern in pattern space - which *does* match a comma with `,*` this time - it matches the comma separating this field and the last. It also matches `HH:MM` in `\1` and *(because that string is immediately followed by a comma)* the `''` null-string in `\2`. All that remains from there is to replace `\1` with itself preceded by a *<space>* and followed by the *:00* string. Both the intervening comma and the null-string are edited away.

If you feel you *would* rather get a little more specific after all, though, consider how much easier it might be with just a little abstraction. The primary benefit offered by regular expressions is that they provide us a means of quickly and efficiently abstracting away a repetitive task given only a clear understanding of what makes it repetitive in the first place.

If constructing your regexp becomes a repetitive task in and of itself, then, well... something's probably missing. One of the advantages of a simple regexp syntax, though, is that it *too* often makes a very good candidate for abstraction - and it is easily achieved.

For example:

```
d='[0-9][0-9]' T=$d:$d m=$d y=$d$d
sed -E "s|($m/$d)/($y),($T)|\2-\1 \3:00|;s|/|-|"
```

Comment: looks like OP wants a space after the date, not a comma

Comment: @glennjackman - thanks. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Interesting - a bit like self-modifying code. +1

Answer (score 2):

And possible `awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","; } { split($1, d, "/"); $2 = d[3] "-" d[1] "-" d[2] " " $2 ":00"; $1 = ""; } { for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) printf("%s", $i OFS); printf("%s", $NF ORS);}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a slightly different approach - parse the timestamp, then spit out a formatted timestamp. And I'd use `perl` for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $input_format  = '%m/%d/%Y,%H:%M';
my $output_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

while (<>) {
    my ( $date, $time, @stuff ) = split(",");
    my $timestamp = Time::Piece->strptime( "$date,$time", $input_format );
    print join( ",", $timestamp->strftime($output_format), @stuff );
}
```

Which you can reduce to a one liner thus:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lne '($date,$time,@stuff) = split; print join ( ',', Time::Piece->strptime( "$date,$time", "%m/%d/%Y,%H:%M" ) -> strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), @stuff);'
```

Which with your sample data, spits out:

```
1998-01-02 09:45:00,0.4592,0.4613,0.4529,0.4571,9956023
1998-01-02 10:00:00,0.4571,0.4613,0.455,0.4613,8939555
1998-01-02 10:15:00,0.4613,0.4697,0.4571,0.4697,12823627
1998-01-02 10:30:00,0.4676,0.4969,0.4613,0.4906,28145145
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
sed -n 's_^\([^/]*\)/\([^\]*\)/\([^,]*\),\([^:]*\):\([^,]*\)_\3-\1-\2 \4:\5:00_p' file.txt
```

Comment: To get the correct *date* format, it needs `-\1-\2`, not `-\2-\1`

Comment: @Peter.O edited..